# A Perplexing Puzzle

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

## The Challenge

Create a program or function that takes no input, and outputs (or returns):

```
I'm a programming paradox — no I'm not.
```

Without using a character twice in any string, or digit twice in any integer.

---

## Rules

1. You may not use any character twice *within a string*. For example, the word `"test"` would violate this rule.
2. You may not use any character twice *between strings*. For example, if somewhere in your code you have the string `"hi"`, no other strings may contain the substring `"h"` or `"i"`.
3. You may not use a digits more than once *within an integer*. For example, the integer `200` would not be acceptable.
4. You may not use a digit more than once *between integers*. For example, if you have the integer `40` in your code, you may  not have the integer `304`.
5. The above rules do not apply between data types. You could, for example, have the string `"9"` and the integer `9` in your code.
6. An uppercase letter is considered a separate character from the lowercase.
7. You may only use printable ASCII characters in your strings.
8. You may not set variables to each character and add them together.

---

## Example

Here is an example, written in Python 2, of what the same challenge might look like with the string "Hello, World!" instead.

```
print"He"+"l"*2+"o, "+"W"+chr(int("1"*3))+"r"+chr(108)+"d!"
```

---

<sup>Note: For those wondering why I chose this particular string; I chose it because it has several repeated characters and a repeated word. It has no greater significance or meaning.</sup>

Comment: Does the repeated rule only apply to strings, and not the rest of the code?

Comment: Correct. It only applies to strings and integers. @ASCIIThenANSI

Comment: Does this apply to format strings? For example, using printf("%s%s") in C?

Comment: Yep. @TobErnack

Comment: I don't like that you added a rule to rule out a posted answer. It's not fair to ETHproductions that they figured out a solution but don't get to use it because you don't like it. Also, I don't think saving chars to variables is any more cheap than using character codes as in your example.

Comment: What if I mash together characters *without* setting variables to them?

Comment: I suppose that's alright. @dfeuer

Comment: -1 for changing the rules.

Comment: The dash in the text "I'm a programming paradox — no I'm not." you posted is not ASCII 39 "-"

Comment: It's not clear to me whether when you say *string* you mean *string literal*, and similarly for *integer* vs *integer literal*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>89</s> <s>86</s> 84 Bytes

```
`${y=>I0m3a3programming3paradox313no3I0m3not2}`.slice(3).replace(/\d/g,m=>"'—. "[m])
```

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, <s>186</s> <s>155</s> <s>139</s> <s>138</s> <s>126</s> <s>109</s> 98 bytes

I don't know if this is a loophole...

```
OKDLPLGHFBHPDDCEBLGPHPAFJLMLEFLOKDLEFIN=0
print list(locals())[3].translate("adgimnoprtx' -.I"*16)
```

<s>don't think</s> I can golf more than this...

Comment: Very nicely done!

Comment: This seems to use `3` twice in integers `35` and `39`. You could always use `42-7` for `35` or something similar though.

Comment: `chr(39)` can be replaced with `"'"` and `chr(35)` with `"#"`. Saves you bytes and puts you in the rules. Also, you can do `r=replace` and save a ton of bytes. You're also calling `list` twice.

Comment: `r=replace` is not valid syntax in Python. @MorganThrapp

Comment: @ZachGates Right, forgot that was a method of `str`.

Comment: @MorganThrapp You can do `r=str.replace` though. This requires some other changes so idk if it helps golf here, but just an fyi :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yeah, I spent a bit trying to work with that, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @MorganThrapp you have to call `r` like this: `r("My String", "My", "A")` which returns `"A String"`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Right, duh, I forget when you call it as a class method you have to pass in the instance.
@Max `I0m_a_programming_paradox_3_no_I0m_not1="#";r=str.replace
print r(r(r(r(list(locals().iteritems())[4][-2],'0',chr(39)),"_"," "),"1","."),"3","-")` saves you 10 bytes.

Comment: @ETHproductions the little step in previous edit that gave me 1 byte led to the last result of 126 bytes...

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>142</s> <s>105</s> <s>98</s> 96 bytes

```
[a="I'm","a",`${y=>programming}`.slice(3),`${no=>paradox}`.slice(4),'-',x="no",a,x+"t."].join` `
```

Another possible rule-breaker, but it was fun, anyway. :)

Original version:

```
[a="I'm",(''+(b=>a)).substr(3),(''+(is=>programming)).substr(4),(''+(Fermi=>paradox)).substr(7),'-',(''+(yes=>no)).substr(5),a,'not.'].join` `
```

Comment: I don't know ES6 but.... googling i found thath `is=>programming` is like: `function f(is){return programming}` right? I don't understand why this should return the string "programming"?

Comment: @Max Yes, you are correct about the fat arrow function declaration. ```...`${y=>programming}`...``` is the same as `...(''+(y=>programming))...`, (or `...(''+(function(y){return programming;}))...`) which returns `"y=>programming"`, and a substring is taken off of that. Not sure if this is allowed or not.

Comment: does the string concatenation "generate" automagically a string representation of the function?

Comment: @Max Yep. Javascript's type conversion can be ridiculous sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

### C++14, 327 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
#define x(y) <<(y)[s]
std::string s[]={"I'"," ","a","p","r","o","g","m","n","i","d","x","—","t","."};enum{J,S,A,P,R,O,G,M,N,I,D,X,W,T,Z};[]{std::cout x(J)x(M)x(S)x(A)x(S)x(P)x(R)x(O)x(G)x(R)x(A)x(M)x(M)x(I)x(N)x(G)x(S)x(P)x(A)x(R)x(A)x(D)x(O)x(X)x(S)x(W)x(S)x(N)x(O)x(S)x(J)x(M)x(S)x(N)x(O)x(T)x(Z);}();
```

I'm defining a macro which returns a string to the `<<` operator, mapping the necessary characters in a string array and access them with an `enum`

Comment: I don't think I can golf this particular solution any more, but tips are always welcome!

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 320 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char

data Letter = A|D|I|I'm|MM|P|R|G|N|O|X|Y|S|T deriving Show

transform :: Letter -> String
transform S = " "
transform Y = "—"
transform I'm = "I'm"
transform x = map toLower $ show x

main :: IO ()
main = print $ transform =<<
   [I'm,S,A,S,P,R,O,G,R,A,MM,I,N,G,S,P,A,R,A,D,O,X,S,Y,S,N,O,S,I'm,S,N,O,T]
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This is Haskell I believe.